# Oracle SQL join local table

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, powerpivot

I included some data to excel via an oracle connection/ sql.
It is just a typical SELECT-FROM-WHERE SQL, for example:

```
SELECT
   ID9.XDAT
   ID9.xIDD
   ID9.XSTR
FROM
   POOLGEN.OPPPID9 ID9
WHERE
   ID9.XIDD > 100000
```

FOr now I am aiming the objective to filter the data on the current month.
The month is a specific company/ business month.
For example: The January is from the 28.12.2018 - 25.01.2019.

I have included this specific calendar to the data model of Excel (Power Pivot).

Is it possible to filter already inside the SQL to the local Excel file and the current month?

The XDAT have the structure of DD.MM.YYYY

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to move that "specific calendar" into Oracle. For example, create a table which would hold those dates:

```
create table business_months 
  (b_month   number,
   date_from date,
   date_to   date
  );
insert into business_months values (1, date '2018-12-28', date '2019-01-25');
insert into business_months values (2, date '2019-01-26', date '2019-02-25');
etc.
```

Then expand your current query so that it uses the `business_months` table:

```
select id9.xdat
       id9.xidd,
       id9.xstr
from poolgen.oppid9 id9 
 join business_months bm on id9.xdat between bm.date_from and bm.date_to
where bm.b_month = 1;    --> January
```